# Are there any way to delete Azure Blob Container files through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-instances

I am currently having a project where I will upload some files in the Blob Container and there are instances that I also want to permanently delete some files but it should be through JavaScript. Are there any ways?

Comment: Sure. You will need to use Azure Storage SDK for JavaScript: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Mantri :) The source you have given was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
const {
    BlobServiceClient
  } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

  const connectionString = '<storage connection string>'
  const container = '<container name>'
  const blob = '<blob name>'

  const blobClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString).getContainerClient(container).getBlobClient(blob);
  blobClient.deleteIfExists().then(result =>{console.log(result._response.status + " blob removed")})
```

Let me know if you have any more questions.